# UbuntuShape component doesn't show the background color.

Tags: application-development

This code gives me an UbuntuShape with the background color red:

```
UbuntuShape{
    height: units.gu(6)
    width: units.gu(6) 
    color:"red"
}
```

but when I set an image with the code below, the background color is not applied.

```
UbuntuShape{
    height: units.gu(6)
    width: units.gu(6) 
    color:"red"

    image: Image{ source: "my_icon.svg"}
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can only use either "image" or "color".

As a workaround you might try this:

```
UbuntuShape {
  color: "red"
  height: units.gu(6)
  width: units.gu(6) 

  Image {
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "my_icon.svg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you also tell me why is that? It's not even mentioned in the documentation.